# Tomcat 7 Error: The requested resource (/TestSite) is not available. Even I deployed correctly. Why?

Tags: ajax, jsp, web-applications, tomcat, deployment

I created a test website for testing an AJAX code. The code calls a servlet from JSP using AJAX. The code compiled successfully and I deployed it in tomcat webapps folder. The folder hierarchy as follows:

[image]

And my ***web.xml*** code is:

> ```
> <web-app>
>   <jsp-file>index.jsp</jsp-file>
>   <servlet>
>       <servlet-name>getname</servlet-name>
>       <servlet-class>getname</servlet-class>
>   </servlet>
>   <servlet-mapping>
>       <servlet-name>getname</servlet-name>
>       <url-pattern>getname</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
> </web-app>
> ```

Now when I try to run this website using my browser as http://localhost:8080/TestSite or http://localhost:8080/TestSite/index.jsp it displays following error:
[image]

**OR this one**

[image]

Even the site is not visible in Tomcat Manager. Also other sites are nicely running from tomcat manager or directly. Please tell me what to do now?

Comment: Look in catalina.out. Are there any errors?

Comment: Oh sorry Alex Actually I found the answer myself. This was a silly mistake by me. ;) Actually I forgot to add a / before servlet name in url-pattern tag and now its running fine ;)

Comment: try using an IDE to avoid such errors.
Also, for deploying WARs, use the management console.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with all my servlets except one, but whatever is causing my problem is different from what you did.

Comment: @JeremyList then post it as a question so that we can know the details.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva I already did that, but no-one answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286540/tomcat-7-deployed-war-404-error-on-servlets-other-files-fine-everything-fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake by me. Actually I forgot to add a `/` before servlet name in url-pattern tag and now its running fine. :)