# Tomcat 7 deployed war: 404 error on servlets, other files fine, everything fine in eclipse

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I have a Java web application which is working perfectly when launched via eclipse's "run in server" menu option, but when I deploy the war file to tomcat running on a VPS it gives a 404 error when trying to access any of the servlets (there is one servlet that's working but I have no idea why it would work and the others wouldn't). All the jsp documents and directly served files are also working fine, it's just the servlets that I can't get to work.

I had originally been using `@WebServlet` annotations, but I deleted them and I'm using web.xml because the server I'm deploying to seems to ignore the annotations, that may have been a waste of time.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <!-- 30天内自动登录（检测COOKIE） -->
  <filter>
        <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>co.fsjr.web.LoginCookie</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/main.jsp</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>adminFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>co.fsjr.web.AdminIntercept</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>adminFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/adminuser/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.web.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CheckCode</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.util.CheckCode</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FlightQuery</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.servlet.FlightQuery</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdminUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.servlet.AdminUserServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FlightSortServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.servlet.FlightSortServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>OrderServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.servlet.OrderServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PrepareDataServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.servlet.PrepareDataServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PayPalServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.servlet.PayPalServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>co.fsjr.servlet.UserServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CheckCode</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/check</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FlightQuery</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FlightQuery</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AdminUserServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FlightSortServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FlightSortServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrderServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrderServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PayPalServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PayPalServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PrepareDataServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PrepareDataServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UserServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/main.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
      <!-- 配置错误处理 -->
    <error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/error/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
       <error-code>505</error-code>
       <location>/505.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <!-- 配置异常处理 -->
    <error-page>
       <exception-type>javax.servle.ServletException</exception-type>
       <location>/errorpage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
       <exception-type>java.lang.NullPointerException</exception-type>
       <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

/check is the servlet that's working properly, but all the other servlet mappings just lead to the 404 error page. Once again: the entire web app is working fine on my local machine, just not on the remote server, even though they ostensibly have the same version of tomcat 7.

Comment: `Check` and other servlets are in same directory?

Comment: The servlet for check is in /WEB-INF/classes/co/fsjr/util, the other are in /WEB-INF/classes/co/fsjr/servlet. But the package prefix is correct, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tomcat as well as JBoss, if there are strange errors, it can help to clear the 'temp' and 'work' folders.  At my work, us dev's have a batch script to clear those folders on server start.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what I ended up doing to fix this would have cleared those directories, so this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this worked:

```
sudo apt-get purge tomcat7
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Problem solved.